# Yii CGridView column value , achieved from model

Tags: php, yii

I wanna make some CGridView table in a view. And one column should contain DropDown list. Main problem is, that this dropdown list must be generated by model.

So, in my view i made it like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$orders->search(),
                'filter' => $orders,
                'columns' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'actions',
                        'header' => 'Actions',
                        'value' => '$data->actions',
                        'filter' => false,


    ),
));
```

And in Order model:

```
public function getActions() {
    return CHtml::dropDownList('status', $this->status->id,  CHtml::listData(Status::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'title'));
}
```

And i getting pretty nice column value with code of this dropdown list, but all special chracters encoded to lt; quot; gt; etc. Just string, not html element.

So, how to get real html dropdown list?

[SOLVED]
just adding 'type' => 'raw' for this column solved all this problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special characters in a CGridView are encoded by default. Try adding the following to your columns array:

```
'type' => 'raw'
```

// Edit: Oops, read your question too fast. I see you've already found the solution yourself. :)